# Hide method/class using @hide in annotation

Tags: java, android, annotations, documentation, hide

I am developing a library (jar) for android and have come into a situation where I want my class or method to be accessible within my library only, but not outside my library. Using no modifier will make class accessible within that package, but I am in a situation that this class cannot be used without `public` modifier, because using no modifier will make it inaccessible in other packages which I do not want. For example,
I have a class say,

```
public class Globals {

    public static String thisDeviceAddress;
    public static String thisDeviceIP;
    public static String thisDeviceName = "";

}
```

This class is accessible everywhere. The problem is that I want it to be accessible within my library that I am developing, but not outside the library. I have come to know that using annotation `@hide` will solve the issue. For example:

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
class Globals {

    public static String thisDeviceAddress;
    public static String thisDeviceIP;
    public static String thisDeviceName = "";
}
```

I googled alot about it but could not find a way to implement `@hide`. Just using `@hide` without a library didn't hide the class. So, please provide me proper guidance. Any library to be used? any way out to solve this problem?

Comment: `@hide` won't work - it just removes a symbol from the stub android.jar when the SDK is built so code cannot be written to directly access them. The symbols will be there in the runtime and can be accessed via reflection. But that's not a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have no problem if class/method get accessed via reflection. But I do not want it to be directly visible. If it works,please let me know what needs to be setup to use @hide.

Comment: @Dipendra, I have same situation here. Did you find out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to hide public classes and methods. It's Java language specification and you cannot broke that.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work you will need to change your distribution model to include *two* jars:

1. A "compile-time-only" API jar that only has public/non-hidden "stubs" for your library.
2. A "run-time implementation" jar that contains all needed code for the library (the current aar/jar you are getting by default when building the library).

To use `@hide` and generate the API stubs, you have to use `Doclava` (a custom `javadoc` Doclet that implements `@hide` and has an option to generate stubs).

You can generate the API stubs jar by following these steps:

1. Get the custom `Doclava` doclet from Google, which you can clone and build yourself from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/doclava/ or you can download a prebuilt jar fom https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.doclava/doclava.
2. Place the Doclava jar in a directory at the library root (next to the `src` directory) e.g., `/path/to/project/mylib/doclava/doclava.jar`.
3. Change your `build.gradle` as follows:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...

    // Make implementation and compileOnly classes accessible to other tasks.
    configurations.getAt("implementation").setCanBeResolved(true)
    configurations.getAt("compileOnly").setCanBeResolved(true)
}

// A gradle task to generate the stubs using Doclava.
task generateStubSources(type: Javadoc) {
    source = [file('src/main/java')]
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/api/stub-sources" 
    title = null

    options {
        bootClasspath = project.files(
                project.android.getBootClasspath(),
                configurations.implementation,
                configurations.compileOnly
        ).getFiles().asList()

        doclet = 'com.google.doclava.Doclava'
        docletpath = fileTree(dir: 'doclava', include: '**/*.jar').asType(List)
        addFileOption 'stubs', file("$buildDir/api/stub-sources")
        addBooleanOption 'hide 111', true
        addBooleanOption 'hide 113', true
        addBooleanOption 'keepstubcomments', true
        addBooleanOption 'stubsourceonly', true
        addBooleanOption 'nodocs', true
        addBooleanOption 'android', true

        noTimestamp false
        jFlags '-Dignore.symbol.file'
    }
}

// A task to compile the stubs.
task compileStubs(type: JavaCompile, dependsOn: 'generateStubSources') {
    source = fileTree("$buildDir/api/stub-sources")
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/api/stub-classes")
    classpath = files(source, generateStubSources.options.bootClasspath)
}

// A task to jar the compiled stubs.
task jarStubs(type: Jar) {
    from compileStubs
    destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/api")
    archiveBaseName = 'api'
}

// The full task to generate the API stubs jar.
task generateAndJarStubs(dependsOn: ['generateStubSources', 'jarStubs'])

afterEvaluate {
    // Generate and jar the stubs after building the actual project.
    compileReleaseSources.finalizedBy(generateAndJarStubs)
    compileDebugSources.finalizedBy(generateAndJarStubs)
}
```

4. Build your project as usual. An API stubs jar file will appear under `/path/to/project/mylib/build/api/api.jar`. You can distribute and use this `api.jar` file as usual as a `compileOnly` dependency.

... And do not forget to use/package the actual implementation jar/aar of the library at deployment time!